# Spyder - Editor panel shown twice after unknown shortcut

Tags: editor, spyder

I entered some shortcut in Spyder from the WinPython\WPy64-3950 collection.
I think "Ctrl+Shift+..."

Now there's a second editor open, that I can't get rid off so far..
It's not exactly mirroring the first one. I guess it is usually used
to keep a good overview over your code, especially if the code is longer.

[image]

I want to close this second editor panel. None of the following shortcuts seem to help:
http://e-callisto.org/cospar2018/SpyderKeyboardShortcutsEditor.pdf

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close an Editor panel you can go to the options menu of the panel and there you should find the action `Close this panel`. The shortcut for the action is `Alt + Shift + W`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help. Somehow I completely oversaw that option.  I added an image in my original post for clarity, in case that others have the same issue at some point.